# define a counter in application.properties in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a complex list of objects that must be set value in the properties file.
Normally I defined that like this:

```
myApp.persons[1].name=Adam
myApp.persons[1].age=20
myApp.persons[1].score=101

myApp.persons[2].name=Jeams
myApp.persons[2].age=25
myApp.persons[2].score=84
```

This is good when the list is small but when the count of the index is grown, the properties file will be complex for add or remove one of the indexes of the list.
Is there any solution to solve this purpus?

I think may there is a way to define a counter in properties file like(Of course I dindn't find any response in my searching) :

```
    counter=1;
    myApp.persons[${counter}].name=Adam
    myApp.persons[${counter}].age=20
    myApp.persons[${counter}++].score=101
    
    myApp.persons[${counter}].name=Jeams
    myApp.persons[${counter}].age=25
    myApp.persons[${counter}++].score=84
```

Comment: Might be worth looking at creating a Bash script to do add/remove operations.

Comment: _must be set in the properties file_ Why, _exactly_? For example, why can you not use `@Resource("classpath:persons.yaml")`?